# Add values as array to object key-pair

Tags: javascript

I want to add values to empty object to their correct key that is received dynamically.

Obviously the following does not work because I replace the existing value of that key with the latest value:

```
let obj = {};

let key;
let value;

key = // from selectors 
value = // from selectors 

obj[key] = value;
```

How can I "push" the new value to that key instead of replacing it?

For example if `value1` and `value2` were chosen after 2 iterations with `key1` then the end result of the object would be

```
{"key1": ['value1', 'value2']}
```

Comment: Just putting it out there - this question has already been answered. You should mark one of them as a solution before all of stackoverflow posts their own solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. A common way is to set `obj[key]` equal to itself, defaulting it to an empty array with `?? []` ([nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)) if it is `null`/`undefined`, ie: [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)), and then using [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to return a new array with the added value:

```js
obj[key] = (obj[key] ?? []).concat(value); // ?? can be replaced with `||` for better browser support
```

Or use `??=` ([nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)) to set `obj[key]` to an empty array if it's nullish, and then push into that array `.push()` to update the existing array

```js
(obj[key] ??= []).push(value);
```

The above works because `obj[key] ?? = []` will set `obj[key]` to `[]` if `obj[key]` is `undefined`/`null`, and then return the reference to the array stored at `obj[key]`, that being the array we just created or the array that already exists at `obj[key]`. We can then `.push()` into this array reference which updates it in `obj`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (obj[key] === undefined) obj[key] = []
obj[key].push(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're assigning, just add to the array or create one if it doesn't exist

```js
obj[key] = [...(obj[key] ?? []), value];
```

,

```js
obj[key] = (obj[key] ?? []).concat(value);
```

, or

```js
if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
obj[key].push(value);
```